# Is it possible to first scale an image and then let it resize (9patch) in Android?

Tags: android, image, imageview, scaling, nine-patch

I am wondering whether in android this is possible or not: I have got an image that contains a picture surrounded by a frame. This image is a 9 patch image, so that I can use it on different sized screens. However, the 9 patch does not scale down proportionally so that on small screens I end up with a frame that is too thick.

Now: Is it possible to first scale (down or up) the original image and after that let it resize with the 9 patch functionality?

If so, can someone give me an example? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not how 9-patches are designed to work. However, you might consider providing a different version of your 9-patch for different densities or perhaps even screen sizes. This is a [common and recommended practice](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for images in general.